# Getting the index length of a particular struct type

Tags: rust

I have a custom Struct that consists of two `i32` types that make out a 2D vector. I have been accessing certain indices using `for` loops, but I have yet to figure out how to get the length of either 'col or 'row'. Here's my code:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Vec2d {
    col: i32,
    row: i32,
}


fn main() {
    let mut vec_struct = Vec::new();

    for i in 0..5 {
        for j in 0..7 {  
            let index = [
                Vec2d {
                    col: j * 3,
                    row: i * 5,
                },
            ];
            vec_struct.push(index);
        }
    }

    // I want to get 5 or 7 somehow, but none of these two work
    println!("{}", vec_struct[0][0].len());
    println!("{}", vec_struct[0].len());
    
    // This works, but prints both dimensions (output: 35)
    println!("{}", vec_struct.len());
}
```

Comment: The compiler is inferring `vec_struct`'s type based on how you're using it. Since you're using it incorrectly it's inferring the wrong type, leading to confusing behavior. Try assigning it a known type: `let mut vec_struct: Vec<???> = Vec::new();`. What replaces `???`? Telling the compiler that will let it produce more helpful error messages.

Comment: My understanding is that "let mut vec_struct: Vec<Vec2d> = Vec::new();" should be what you're suggesting, but that gives me an error when i do vec_struct.push(index). I have already declared the elements to be the type i32 in the struct, so I don't think I need to re-initialize them at the later stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're storing your elements in a flat `Vec`, you've lost the information of where each column/row starts and ends.

You can either store them in a nested `Vec<Vec<Vec2d>>`, or try to restore this information armed with the knowledge that a new column starts when the column number is zero:

```rust
let columns = vec_struct
    .iter()
    .enumerate()
    .skip(1) // The first column is always zero, skip it
    .find_map(|(i, Vec2d { col, .. })| if *col == 0 { Some(i) } else { None })
    .unwrap();
let rows = vec_struct.len() / columns;
```

You stored the elements in one-element array (`[Vec2d { ... }]`). I guess you tried to do the first solution, but this array will always stay one-element-sized. You need to use a vector like that:

```rust
for i in 0..5 {
    let mut row = Vec::new();
    for j in 0..7 {
        let index = Vec2d {
            col: j * 3,
            row: i * 5,
        };
        row.push(index);
    }
    vec_struct.push(row);
}
let rows = vec_struct.len();
let columns = vec_struct[0].len();
```